# How to set active profile in Vertx similar to Spring Boot

Tags: vert.x

I have a vertx-config-git verticle set up which tracks a config repo setup in github. The repo contains configurations(json files) specific to DEV, QA, STATE and PROD in different folders. But since Vertx Config pulls all the config files, the configurations are overridden by the last json file read from the repo. Is there a way to get only the environment specific configurations based on a env variable passed  during deployment?

```
@Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    ConfigStoreOptions env = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("env");
    ConfigStoreOptions git = new ConfigStoreOptions()
        .setType("git")
        .setConfig(new JsonObject()
            .put("url", "https://github.com/kaushik-Das/vertx-config")
            .put("path", "local")
            .put("filesets",
                new JsonArray().add(new JsonObject().put("pattern", "*.json"))));


    ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(env).addStore(git);

    ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx,
        options.setScanPeriod(1000));

    retriever.getConfig().setHandler(ar -> {
      if (ar.failed()) {
        System.out.println(ar.cause());
      } else {
        JsonObject config = ar.result();
        System.out.println(config.encodePrettily());
      }
    });

    retriever.listen(listener -> {
      JsonObject newConfiguration = listener.getNewConfiguration();
      System.out.println(newConfiguration);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of vert.x v.3.8.5, no support for Profiles as they are understood in the Spring world is available.

However, the pattern for the filesets [follows the Ant style](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_git_configuration_store). So something like this should be possible:

```java
String stageName = getStageName(); // get stage identifier, e.g. from an environment variable

ConfigStoreOptions env = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("env");
ConfigStoreOptions git = new ConfigStoreOptions()
    .setType("git")
    .setConfig(new JsonObject()
        .put("url", "https://github.com/kaushik-Das/vertx-config")
        .put("path", "local")
        .put("filesets",
            new JsonArray().add(new JsonObject().put("pattern", "**/" + stageName + "/*.json"))));
```

If the `stageName` is `"DEV"`, this would result in a pattern `"**/DEV/*.json"` including only json files in a subfolder with the name `DEV`.